# Trouble creating list objects with a loop, and looking for good structure practices

Tags: c#, list

As a way of learning C# I'm working on a small adventure game with card battles. I'm running into a little trouble with generating the cards though. What I'm trying to do is generate some random values for the cards, instantiate them, then assign the new objects to a list which is the "hand" the player is dealt. this is what I have so far:

```
        public void generateBattleCards()
    {
        string cardStat;
        string cardName;
        int cardValue;
        string[] stats = { "Power", "Precision", "Allure", "Vitality", "Essence" };
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            cardStat = stats[random.Next(0, stats.Length)];
            cardValue = random.Next(1, 10);
            cardName = cardValue.ToString() + " of " + cardStat;
            Card newCard = new Card(cardName, cardStat, cardValue);
            CardHand.Add(newCard);
        }

        picPlayerCard1.Image = CardHand[0].cardImage;
        picPlayerCard2.Image = CardHand[1].cardImage;
        picPlayerCard3.Image = CardHand[2].cardImage;
        picPlayerCard4.Image = CardHand[3].cardImage;
        picPlayerCard5.Image = CardHand[4].cardImage;
    }
```

I'm getting a null reference where I add the card to the list.

After struggling with this for awhile it occurred to me that this probably isn't the most elegant way to structure this assuming I get it to work. So if anyone has input on how to structure this better I would be grateful.

As a side note, I would like to use player stats from a player class as the min and max values for cardStat. I haven't figured out a good way to grab the right stat value based on the random stat name chosen. The stats exist in the player class as private int with properties for get and set.

While trying to figure this out myself I ran into info on dictionaries. I've never used one before, but would it be worth looking into creating all possible cards, storing them, and retrieving only the cards I need instead of trying to create them each time?

Thanks for any help or feedback you feel like giving :)

Comment: CardHand is probably null; make sure you initialize it before trying to use it.

Comment: Also, you should put `Random random = new Random();` outside the loop, otherwise you will likely pick the same values every time...

Comment: That's a good point Thomas, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting a null reference where I add the card to the list.

`CardHand` is not declared within that method, so wherever you do it, you are apparently not *initializing* it.

So somewhere, you should have the following:

```
CardHand = new List<Card>();
```

Then before the loop within `generateBattleCards` you should clear that list to make sure that you don’t keep previous cards:

```
CardHand.Clear();
```

---

In general, I would separate the random card generation from where you are creating the player’s hand. This would allow you to draw cards separately (which might be useful to your game).

Furthermore, you should also separete the game logic (drawing cards etc.) from the visual logic (which icon to show where). E.g. just let the Forms controller access the player’s cards and leave it completely to it how to display them.

```
// keep the random generator around
private readonly Random rand = new Random();

// keep the stats around; even better: make an Enum with those values
private readonly string[] stats = { "Power", "Precision", "Allure", "Vitality", "Essence" };

private Card DrawNewCard ()
{
    string stat = stats[random.Next(0, stats.Length)];
    int value = GetRandomValueForStat(stat);
    string name = string.Format("{0} of {1}", value, stat);

    return new Card(name, value, stat);
}

public void generateBattleCards()
{
    CardHand.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        CardHand.Add(DrawNewCard());
    }
}
```

Comment: Argh, I can't believe I missed that! Haha, thanks so much for pointing it out, it works perfectly now!

Comment: Again, super helpful! This cleans things up quite a bit, thanks.